# GEM Editor - How do I make that if something dies, the mission is failed

Tags: men-of-war-assault-squad-2

In the gem editor of Men of War Assault Squad 2.

I am wondering on how to do this: If a certain amount of units dies, the mission is failed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tag a number of men you start the mission with any name and if they are all killed during the mission you lose the mission.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to go into more detail, explaining how exactly to do this.